# Почему в двух списках копятся значения?

Tags: python, ооп

**Задача**

Решить проблему с накоплением значений в списках new_list_1 и new_list_2 при вызове нескольких раз одной функции, при следующем коде ->

**Мой код**

```
class ListNode(object):
     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
         self.val = val
         self.next = next
class Solution(object):
    def mergeTwoLists(self, list1, list2, new_list_1 = [], new_list_2 = []):
        """
        :type list1: Optional[ListNode]
        :type list2: Optional[ListNode]
        :rtype: Optional[ListNode]
        """
        def list_to_ListNode(l, d = {}):
            d.clear()
            for num, value in enumerate(l[::-1]):
                d['val'] = value
                if num == 0:
                    d['next'] = None
                    y = ListNode(d['val'], d['next'])
                else:
                    y = ListNode(d['val'], y)
            return y
        if list1 != None:
            for key,value in list1.__dict__.items():
                if isinstance(value, int):
                    new_list_1.append(value)
                else:
                    return self.mergeTwoLists(value, list2)
        if list2 != None:
            for key,value in list2.__dict__.items():
                if isinstance(value, int):
                    new_list_2.append(value)
                else:
                    return self.mergeTwoLists(list1, value)

        total_list = new_list_1 + new_list_2
        total_list.sort()
        total_list = list_to_ListNode(total_list)
        new_list_1 = []
        new_list_2 = []
        return total_list
```

**Примечание**

Если вам интересна сама задача, то вот ссылка на неё -> https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists
Я знаю, как её решить *нормальным* способом, я хочу понять почему в переменных new_list_1 и new_list_2 лежат даже после:

```
new_list_1 = [] 
new_list_2 = []
```

Они продолжают лежать там после при попытке вывести следующий результат. Пробовал многое, но мне ничего не помогло.

Comment: Вы неправильно работаете с аргументами по умолчанию в параметрах функции: `def mergeTwoLists(self, list1, list2, new_list_1 = [], new_list_2 = []):`. Туда не нужно помещать изменяемые объекты, если собираетесь их менять :) Эти параметры инициализируются только один раз - при объявлении функции. Поэтому, при каждом вызове функции, если вы не указываете явно параметры `new_list_1` и `new_list_2`, будут использоваться объявленные в функции. Правильно объявить их равными, например, `None`, а уже внутри функции проверять, что если параметр `is None`, то параметр равен `[]`

Comment: С `def list_to_ListNode(l, d = {}):` такая же проблема

Comment: И да, `new_list_1 = []` в конце функции не работает. Но вот `new_list_1.clear()` сработает )  Хотя всё-равно так лучше не делать, а делать через дефолтный параметр `new_list_1 = None`, как выше написано.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, я помню эту штуку, но именно в этой задаче забыл. А вообще изменяемые объекты можно же помещать в функции или этого следует избегать?

Comment: Можно, если вы понимаете, что делаете. Например, я сегодня тут где-то приводил пример, как вместо `lru_cache` можно дефолтный параметр функции использовать для сохранения значений )